# Find example of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int u_n \neq \int u$

Tags: measure-theory

I my homework I have to find an example of $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int u_n \neq \int u$$ for a positive decreasing sequence $u_n$ where $u=\inf \, u_n$

My idea is to set $u_n=1/n  \cdot 1_{[1,n]}$

Hence
$$\lim \int u_n=1 \neq \int \lim u_n = \int u = 0$$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

However I am not sure if the rightside actually is 0. Because it doesn't say anything about pointwise in my textbook

Any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct,and the functions you chose,they converge to zero pointwise, since $$\frac{1}{n}1_{[1,n]}\leq \frac{1}{n},\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$

Now with the Lebesgue measure you can take the sequence $f_n=\frac{x}{n}$ on $(0,+\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

For $x<1$, then all $u_{n}(x)=0$. For $x\geq 1$, pick a large $n_{0}$ such that $1\leq x\leq n_{0}$, then $1\leq x\leq n$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$ and hence $u_{n}(x)=1/n$, so $u_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$.

In either case, $u(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_{n}(x)=0$.